# I can't call a static function from another controller in codeigniter. Why?

Tags: codeigniter

I have started to create a controller called **User** in codeigniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class User extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->library(array( 'encrypt', 'form_validation' ));
        }

        public function index()
        {                
        }

        /*
         * Create loginform
         * Parameters:  void
         * Return:      html of loginform;
         */
        public static function loginform() {

                // Login form setup
                $loginform_data = array();                  
                $loginform_data['attributes']       = array('id'  => 'loginform');  
                $loginform_data['username']         = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'username',
                                                            'id'          => 'username',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );                
                $loginform_data['pass']             = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'pass',
                                                            'id'          => 'pass',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );      

                $contentdata = array();
                $contentdata['loginform'] = $this->load->view('partials/forms/login', $loginform_data, true);
                return $contentdata;
        }

        /*
         * Check login username, password from form
         * Parameters:  void
         * Return:      void;
         */
        public function login() {
                $name = $this->input->post('username');
                $pass = $this->input->post('pass');

                $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Användarnamn', 'required');
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('pass', 'Lösenord', 'required');

                if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
                {
                        $this->load->view('home');
                } 
                else
                {
                        $this->load->view('formsuccess');
                }
            }
}
```

I can call the user/login - function through the url. But I can't call `User::loginform()` from another controller. **Shouldn't I be able to do that?**

Here's what I'm trying: (from my Home-class)

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
                //Create login and register-forms
                $this->load->helper('form');

                //Registration form setup               
                $registerform_data = array();                  
                $registerform_data['attributes']    = array('id'  => 'registerform');  
                $registerform_data['company']       = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'name-company',
                                                            'id'          => 'name-company',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );                
                $registerform_data['orgnr']         = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'orgnr-company',
                                                            'id'          => 'orgnr-company',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );        
                $registerform_data['contact']       = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'contact-company',
                                                            'id'          => 'contact-company',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );                      
                $registerform_data['phonecompany']  = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'phone-company',
                                                            'id'          => 'phone-company',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );                          
                $registerform_data['emailcompany']  = array(
                                                            'name'        => 'email-company',
                                                            'id'          => 'email-company',
                                                            'value'       => '',
                                                            'maxlength'   => '100'                                                    
                                                    );   




                //What content to pass to view       
                $contentdata = array();
                $contentdata['loginform'] = User::loginform();
                $contentdata['registerform'] = $this->load->view('partials/forms/registration', $registerform_data, true);                

                $this->load->view('home', $contentdata);
    }
}
```

`$contentdata['loginform'] = User::loginform();` gives me error:`Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in C:\Program...`

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Why are you using a static method ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a static method either. I just want to call a function from another controller. Is the fact that it is static that messes it up?

Comment: The error is popping up because the user controller is not loaded in your application and you are trying to access it. Change the controller to library or a helper then you can access it from wherever you want.

Comment: I don't want to change the User to a helper because I believe the logic should stay in controllers and not in helpers (or am I wrong?). I just want to access the loginform from anywhere. Would it be correct to create a helper with loginform() and then access that helper from anywhere?

Comment: I suggested the helper because up to now you are using the User class to get a form. So your requirement is to access the loginform() anywhere right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are extending `Home` class ,extend to `User` controller like

```
require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/user.php');
class Home extends User {
```

Because you need to extract the function from `User` class and then it will `Inherit` the parent class `User` functions And since `login_form` is your **public** function in `User` controller,you can call this in `Home` controller now.And no need to use `Static` here I think so.

There is also an way to do this.Just write the `login_form` function in an `helper` and call it on both the controllers then your problem may solve.

**Edit:** As **@IJas** said,we need to include the controller file that you are extending.

Comment: In theory it works, but I still get same kind of error: but at this row: class Home extends User {  (Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\<project>\application\controllers\home.php on line 3 ). I can access the user/loginform directly in the browser and I do get the expected result.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I used it many times.And it works.Anyway I may know another way ,that is to write the function `login_form` in helper and call it on both the controllers. ;-)

Comment: You should include the User controller before extending it. Unless it gives error.

Comment: @IJas - ok . how do I do that?

Comment: @Gautam3164 - If i create a helper of it - Then is it possible to access $this (how?) in $contentdata['loginform'] = $this->load->view('partials/forms/login', $loginform_data, true);

Comment: @IJas sorry for this.Yah we need to include that file....I have edited.Thanks.Actually I missed that in my answer but in my practise generally I wrote it..Silly mistake but costs much..Really thanks.

Comment: @Gautam3164 .. That's fine. All make mistakes :)

Comment: for that you need to create instance on that helper `$ci =& get_instance();` and `$ci->load->view`

Comment: Then, instant of **`$this`**, use **`$ci`**.